How to use dynamic type parameters with mypy?
I need to build a dynamic union of types to be used to create pydantic models dynamically. I am looking how to type the variable to be passed to the Union so mypy is happy.
A simplified snipped would look like this:
from random import choice, randint
from typing import Union

types = (int, str, bool)
a  = tuple(choice(types) for _ in range(randint(1, 10)))
b = Union[a]

mypy raises a valid-type with this code, and I am not really sure how to solve it.
example.py:6: error: Variable "example.a" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
example.py:6: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases

The error is the same with a : Tuple[Type, ...].

You need to go other way around: b = Union[int, str]; a = typing.get_args(b). There was a question about this, I'll find it...

This question is similar to: Dynamically create Literal alias from list of valid values. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am not sure your sample or the question you are referring to solve the situation where the union is dynamical (the bottom snippet). I will edit the question so I only refer to this one and avoid confusions.

And that just makes no sense from static typing perspective: your runtime determines a union subset to use? What should mypy think about that? The only way would be to cover whole union, and a just won't contain all the possible variants. Typechecker can't say anything else: do you want it to typecheck all possible compbinations? (b = Union[int, str, bool]; types = typing.get_args(b); a = tuple(...))

If you strongly insist on telling pydantic about selected members only, you can do if typing.TYPE_CHECKING: ...; else: ... - where first ellipsis does what I posted above, creating a mypy-readable union, and second ellipsis is replaced with your literal construction opaque to the typechecker.

Ok so the right thing to do here might just be to make mypy ignore this, for the reason that dynamically built types are out of its scope.

Yep, that's the way to go with almost all dynamic types - create a fallback better than Any (if possible) in if TYPE_CHECKING and keep doing dynamic things in else.

I think that one approach would be to use 'Literal' types or 'TypeVar', depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Here's how i think that you can use a new strategy:

use Literal Types, if your 'union' is meant to be a fixed set of values:

from typing import Literal, Union

a = Literal['int','str','bool']
b = Union[int, str, bool]


Use TypeVar with Union, if 'mypy' needs to see the exact types, you could define the union upfront and choose dynamically from these.

If the unin must be dynamic, you would typically need to resolve the type issues manually by definning all possible types and selecting or constructing the union


from random import choice, randint
from typing import Union

types = (int, str, bool)
chosen_types = tuple(choice(types) for _ in range(randint(1, 10)))

if len(set(chosen_types)) == 1:
    DynamicUnion = chosen_types[0]
else:
    DynamicUnion = Union[chosen_types]

but,i think that won't work well with 'mypy'.

the last one is to use Pydantic create model if you need to create dynamically create models:

from pydantic import create_model

model_fields = {'value': (Union[tuple(chosen_types)], ...)}
MyDynamicModel = create_model('MyDynamicModel', **model_fields)


The union is indeed used later in my code with pydantic create_model, and the union must be dynamic in my use case. With your second example, mypy raises this issue: so.py:10: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "<typing special form>", variable has type "type[int] | type[str] | type[bool]")  [assignment]

How does pydantic relate to this, even remotely?.. Typevar is for functions and classes, it can't be applied too a free variable. Constructing the Union dynamically won't fly - none of the typecheckers will understand that.
